# Calculate time difference between multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
 | ID   | UserId |   Event   |         Date        |
 |------|--------|-----------|---------------------|
 | 1    | 123    | Start     | 11/07/2017 14:00:00 |
 | 2    | 123    | PauseStart| 11/07/2017 14:52:52 |
 | 3    | 123    | PauseEnd  | 11/07/2017 14:56:03 |
 | 4    | 123    | PauseStart| 11/07/2017 15:39:45 |
 | 5    | 123    | PauseEnd  | 11/07/2017 15:45:10 |
 | 6    | 123    | Finish    | 11/07/2017 17:45:15 |
 | 7    | 124    | Start     | 11/07/2017 18:00:00 |
 | 8    | 124    | PauseStart| 11/07/2017 19:52:52 |
 | 9    | 124    | PauseEnd  | 11/07/2017 20:05:03 |
 | 10   | 124    | Finish    | 11/07/2017 20:45:15 |
```

I want to sum the time of all pauses for every user:

```
 | UserID | TotalPauses(seconds)|  
 |------  |---------------------|         
 | 123    | 720                 |
 | 124    | 840                 |
```

Comment: You will need to create some sub queries, For Each User ID for starters so you are only working with one UserId at a time, then sort by ID, and increment every two. subtract the second from the first and add to total.

Comment: What if there are two pauses in a row?

Comment: What do you mean two pauses in a row? Every event is in a separate row. Every PauseStart has a PauseEnd and every of them is in a new row in sequence.

Comment: wouldn't it be 516 seconds for userid 123 and 731 for userid 124?

Comment: Yes, Numbers I provided are just example, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way with assumption that `PauseStart` is always followed directly by `PauseEnd`.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c2ab/1)**

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS rn
FROM dbo.YourTable
)

SELECT 
    c1.userid
   , SUM(DATEDIFF(s, c1.date, c2.date)) AS [TotalPauses(seconds)]
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.userid = c2.userid 
  AND c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
WHERE c1.event = 'PauseStart'
GROUP BY c1.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *Window* functions on `UserID` partitions:

```
;WITH temp AS (
    SELECT org_table.*, lag(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Date) as prev 
    FROM org_table 
    WHERE Event in ('PauseStart', 'PauseEnd') 
             ), temp2 AS (
                   SELECT UserID , DATEDIFF(s, prev, Date) as pause_time 
                   FROM temp 
                   WHERE Event = 'PauseEnd') 

SELECT UserID, sum(pause_time) as total_pause 
FROM temp2 
GROUP BY UserID
```